# How to produce an XML output file from a stored procedure in Sybase?

Tags: xml, stored-procedures, sybase

I have an event that calls a stored procedure every 10 minutes.I want that SP creates a XML file with the data of a table of my database. Is that possible?If so,how can I create that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming we're looking at Sybase ASE here.
You can turn a SQL query result into an XML document by adding 'for xml' at the end (select a,b,c from t for xml); this is the simplest, there are more advanced options to do this too.
Th resulting XML document cannot be bigger than 16384 bytes. If the table is too large however, you're have to manually compose the XML document into a text variable of to format every row and write is as a line in the XML document.

Putting the XML data into a file can be done in various ways. Simplest is to PRINT the output and redirect the output to a file on the client side. For creating a file on the ASE server's host, create a proxy table that's mapped to a file and INSERT the generated lines of XML into that proxy table.

Comment: Actually it's Sybase SQL Anywhere 16..Sorry, I forgot to write it down